# How to run markdown file in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, output, markdown

I wrote a markdown file `README.md` in vscode but I am unable to see the output of it. Does anyone know how to see the output of the markdown file in vs code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown

Answer (score 3):

You can open preview by pressing this button
[image]

Or by pressing the default shortcut: `Ctrl+K V`